# getting restricted image for google maps API

Tags: python, google-maps, error-handling, urllib

I have a script that grabs images using the google maps static maps. I have only ran it a couple of times today, and there is no way I reached the cap requests of 25,000. Why is this happening?

Here is the error request image:

[image]

my function takes an input of a list of image urls, file name, and folder it goes in:

```
from urllib import urlretrieve
from time import sleep
def fun(urls,name,folder):
    count = 0
    for src in urls:
        count += 1
        file_name = folder + str(count) + '.jpg'
        urlretrieve(src, file_name)
        print str((count/float(len(urls)))*100) + ' percent done! only ' + str(len(urls) - count) + ' more pictures to download'
        sleep(5)
```

The `sleep(5)` is just to ensure that I don't run the requests so fast to google that they deny it and give me the error anyways.

So why am I getting this limit error that you get when you have made more than 25k requests that day? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You can check the headers you get from urlretrieve, if they set any status code.

Comment: I'm confused at what you mean?

Comment: [urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib#urllib.urlretrieve) returns a `(filename, headers)` tuple. you can print the headers and check if the status_code is anything else than 200

Comment: so the header I get for the first url in the list is: `<httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x11258f440>` where do I find the status code? in that link it's in `urlopen` and `getcode` I am not too familiar with urllib other than the basic things it can do

Comment: Sorry, I just checked, the status field seems not to be set. If you don't mind writing the files yourself, you could use the [request](https://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library, especially the part about [binary content](https://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content). The API is much better

Comment: So it turns out that the script made it seem like I was spamming google so they blocked me for a couple hours and put me on limit or something like that. Thanks though.